# Are there any advantages to building a wooden house?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What are the advantages/disadvantages making a minecraft house built out of wooden planks?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Please note that questions should be based on an actual problem to fit our Q&A format. We're not meant to be a forum where you can create a "Minecraft House 2011" thread, there are plenty of alternative sites that already contain these kind of topics. So, please try to build a house yourself and consult us when you have any problems; you might however try something along the lines of "What are some common pitfalls when building a house?" which could turn into a great community wiki to prevent future Minecraft house building problems. Good luck and have fun... :)

Comment: Unfortunately, as you note, this question is very broad and subjective, and neither of these qualities are well-suited, in my opinion, to the format of this site, with detailed high-quality answers. As you note, "sharing your experiences" with building a house only optionally includes the advantages and disadvantages of different houses, which IMO is a much more actual problem people encounter. I would recommend modifying this question to instead focus on whether or not there are advantages or disadvantages to different qualities in a house.

Comment: @Mana I reworded the question, it sounds better now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks better!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Advantages

- Wood is quicker to obtain than cobblestone, as you get 4 wooden planks for each wood block.
- Wood can be farmed (more easily than cobblestone can be), meaning you don't need to destroy the landscape to build your house.
- Transported as logs rather than planks, you can carry a lot more in you inventory (as you can 'expand' the logs into planks as you need them.
- Wood fits better with bookcases, chests etc. to give a more homely aesthetic.

## Disadvantages

- **Fire** caused by lightning
- Creeper explosions will do more damage
- **Fire** caused by lava, expected or otherwise
- Farming trees can be tedious, especially if you have to spend extra time removing the branches from large trees
- **Fire** caused by your own flint and steel in a moment of carelessness

Comment: You know, I was going to answer this question, but when two more answers came up while I was still typing, I gave up. +1 for the awesome disadvantages pic.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that the "disadvantage" can happen from lightning hitting the house, not just careless use of flint & steel.  Same applies for wooden roofs as well... which I use almost exclusively.  Whoops.

Comment: +1'ed and funny, but you should consider at least saying a few lines on how/why you can end up with a fiery mess if building wooden structures. Also a possible solution to burnt mess is making a glass ceiling.

Comment: A silly question deserves a silly answer, but I added some actual info anyway...

Comment: Re: Advantage 2: Have you *seen* how easy and compact that cobblestone generators have become?

Comment: @John The lava might set your wooden house on fire though...

Comment: True, but that's assuming you don't build your house out of all the cobblestone you're generating.

Comment: The picture is perfect.

Comment: The picture just made my day.

Comment: I'm curious about where you get the first image from. Also, curious about how you managed to generate the second, animated image. (unless you stole it!) ;)

Comment: Upvote for the gif of a wood house burning. It may not be worth a thousand words, but it's definitely worth a paragraph.

Comment: FIRE DOES NOT WORK THAT WAY! ... any more ... I believe it only burns a few blocks before going out now.

Comment: ["Aaaand I just nerfed fire. It will no longer spread infinitely."](https://twitter.com/#!/notch/statuses/72582596294483969) (from [Fire at Minecraft Wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Fire))

Comment: The first image (now gone?!) was just a google image search. I can't remember the exact terms. The newer image is less accurate, as fire does *not* work like that, whereas the original image perfectly conveyed the *feeling* of your house catching fire...

Comment: The picture is gone!  :(

Comment: Found the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5UkDY.jpg

Comment: Cobblestone is extremely easy to farm - make a generator with a lava source and a water source!

Comment: The generator stopped working after the recent minecraft update (fixed piston duplication bug)

Answer (score 9):

Advantages:

- Planks are renewable, as trees are a limitless source. Cobblestone will eventually run out (unless you use lava flows, but that could be dangerous).
- Much easier to construct and bulldoze. You get 4 planks for each trunk of wood, and with any axe trees go down a lot faster than stone. You can even break it unarmed to save tool uses if you're not in a rush, whereas with stone, you don't get anything.
- It matches bookcases, fences, and some other decorative objects better.
- If you completely run out of planks and need something in a jiffy, you can just pop a hole in your house and use the wood from it.

Disadvantages:

- It's easy to destroy; either by fire or creeper blasts.
- You generally won't end up with piles upon piles of planks just by doing mining, whereas with cobblestone you'll likely be overflowing in it.
- You have to plant trees to get more wood for building. This might not be such a big deal if you're harvesting them to get wood for tools, though.

Personally, I find wood buildings to be more eye-pleasing, but that's pretty subjective. Cobblestone, especially in the default skin, is pretty busy looking.

Comment: Granted wood is *easier* to come by, but given that Minecraft will generate new terrain (until killed by rounding errors), cobblestone is *effectively* infinite also. Unless you're making a 1:1 scale model of Mordor, you're unlikely to *ever* run out of cobblestone.

Comment: Cobblestone is renewable (using lava flows, like you said). It's not that dangerous to build a [cobblestone generator](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Cobblestone_farming), you just need to be a bit careful.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert, but there are a few fairly obvious points to start:

- Planks are more easily destroyed by creeper explosions than (for example) cobblestone.
- Planks can catch fire and are consumed, which isn't true of some other materials.
- Cobblestone is readily available in practically unlimited quantities, whereas wood for planks is less common and requires a little crafting--so it's a less efficient use of your time.

One advantage is that you'll probably get sick of seeing nothing but stone buildings after a short while, so a plank structure will look nicer in comparison.

Comment: Your disadvantages are awesome advantages if you want to demolish your wooden house, e.g. by burning it down. :)

Comment: @Exa: TNT is about as awesome though.

Comment: Oh yeah, just used it on my "first shelter".

Answer (score 0):

The one thing no one has mentioned yet is the fact that wood buttons produce a slightly longer pulse. This does't matter unless you are going for a precise timing. Most redstone contraptions however will be fine with either stone or wood.